# fetching discord messages with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a multilingual bot to text-to-speech since it currently supports limited languages.
I am new to discord bot programming. Can anyone help?

The current output is this, which doesn't include any messages.

```
discord.client logging in using static token
discord.gateway Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID:xxxx).
Logged in as xxxx#xxxx
```

Also I would like to know how to make it real-time.
I need it to read out the message once a message is sent.

This is my progress so far.

```
import discord

import asyncio

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

# I did replace with my own bot token

TOKEN = 'xxxx'

@client.event

async def on_ready():

    print(f'Logged in as {client.user}')

@client.event

async def on_message(message):

    # Replace with the ID of the channel you want to fetch messages from

    channel_id = ID

    if message.channel.id == channel_id:
# I also changed the channel id

        print(f'{message.author}: {message.content}')

async def fetch_messages():

    # Replace with the ID of the channel you want to fetch messages from

    channel_id = 1084766415279620159

    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)

    messages = await channel.history(limit=100).flatten()

    for message in messages:

        print(f'{message.author}: {message.content}')

# Start the client and fetch messages

client.run(TOKEN)

asyncio.run(fetch_messages())
```

This is the code I got from asking ChatGPT, with my correction, which is adding intents on line 3.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the first problem you have is that your `intents` are wrong. You need to enable the `message_content` intent if you want to read the message content of messages.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

[Discord docs on intents](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway) and [discord.py docs on intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html). You will need to enable the message content intent in the Discord developer portal for your bot as well otherwise you will get an error.

Secondly, your `fetch_messages` function will never get run. This is because `client.run` loops and nothing after it will get run. There are a couple of ways of handling running code after this but a way that might be appropriate for you is to use [`tasks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html). A simple example below but refer to the link for more options:

```py
# with your imports
from discord.ext import tasks


@tasks.loop(minutes=30)
async def fetch_and_print_messages():
    channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    messages = await channel.history(limit=100).flatten()
    for message in messages:
        print(f'{message.author}: {message.content}')


# create our own `setup_hook` method to start the task after bot logs in
async def setup_hook(self):
    fetch_and_print_messages.start()


client.setup_hook = setup_hook
client.run(TOKEN)
```

You might want to play around with the `channel.history` options if this does get run regularly but this will enable you to fetch messages at regular intervals. If you do only want to run it once, then:

```py
@tasks.loop(minutes=30, count=1)
async def fetch_and_print_messages():
    # rest of code
```

`tasks.loop` takes a `count` parameter that enables you to specify how many times it should loop - we can set that to 1 and it'll only run once.